# Use ivy.xml to have different dependencies in test and prod

Tags: ivy

Due to some legacy issues I'm currently commenting one line in ivy.xml out in local development and putting it back in when commiting code for test/prod.

```
<dependencies defaultconf="default->default">
<dependency org="acme" name="acme-common" rev="4.12-+">
  <exclude org="external" module="slf4j"/>   <----- this one is commented out in local
  <exclude org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-api"/>
  <exclude org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-simple"/>
</dependency>
....
</dependencies>
```

As this is prone to have mistakes when commiting (forgetting to uncomment it) I wonder if it is possible to have different conf. for development and test/prod?